# Firebase cloud functions with google application credentials for text to speech API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am starting the Firebase emulators with

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=c:\code\firebase-admin-sdk.json
firebase emulators:start
```

and the code in index.js is

```
  const googleConfig = async () => {
  const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    scopes: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform",
  });
  const client = await auth.getClient();
  const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();
  const url = `https://dns.googleapis.com/dns/v1/projects/${projectId}`;
  const res = await client.request({url});
  console.log(res.data);
};

let googleTextToSpeechClient;

async function globalConfig() {
  dotenv.config();
  admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
  });
  const db = admin.firestore();
  db.settings;
  await googleConfig();
  googleTextToSpeechClient = new googleTextToSpeech.TextToSpeechClient();
}

globalConfig();
```

google auth doesn't get the credentials. In my google console the firebase-admin key is valid. do I need another key from google cloud or does the firebase admin key let you access all enabled APIs?

Answer (score 1):

The emulators are setting the variable for you so the GOOGLE_APPLICATIONS_CREDENTIALS doesn't have to be set at all.